# Angular Animations apply conditionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-animations

I applied `fadein` effect of [Angular-Animations](https://github.com/filipows/angular-animations) to my Angular project based on ASP.NET, and display only the first row faded-in. However, the other rows are not displayed when using *ngIf as shown below:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-row let-i="rowIndex">
    <tr *ngIf="i==0" [@fadeInOnEnter]>
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/detail/']">{{ row.Summary }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I know that `else` can be used in this situation, but I do not want to repeat lots of `<td>` blocks omitted in this example. So, is there a way to display animation only if the condition is true in `*ngIf` field and display the same block without animation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just apply the condition to the animation?

```
[@fadeInOnEnter]="i == 1"
```

Comment: Yes, I exactly tried this but when using it all of the i values display animations. On the other hand, when using multiple conditions i.e. `[attr.@fadeInOnEnter]="i === 0 ? '' : null"` it only display one value. BUT I want to display all values and animate one of them. Any idea?